# Communicating with a Compute role with Service bus vs. WCF

Tags: c#, azure

Given a simple high level architecture, e.g a cloud service with a web role, and a compute role, under what circumstances would we choose to use WCF as the communication method between the web role and the compute role, rather than service bus.

There is a lot of documentation, and examples regarding service bus, but I would like to understand if there are any platform benefits to using Service Bus, rather than WCF.

Given the calls are synchronous, and short, e.g a typical API call for getting data onto the website, would you choose WCF over queuing messages and replies onto a queue?

It would appear logically that for a synchronous call WCF would offer the least amount of overhead and latency?

I don't fully understand if the platform offers any "clever" tricks to keep the service bus operating as quickly as a TCP connection over WCF, (Given the queuing overhead?) and would like to understand this further.

At the moment if I was to pick an implementation for this type of call I would choose WCF, which maybe a little naive.

Just to clear, the calls always return data, they are not long running, or fire and forget.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on what specifically you want to do.

Service Bus is typically used more for what I would call constant contact type interactions.  It should be more performant, but more complex to set up.  It also has bi-directional communication capabilities.  So you get a lot of extra flexibility out of it.

I would swap WCF for the more modern Web Api.  Both solve the same core problem primarily in serving up content.  I think of it as just that an API, not necessarily a platform for message passing and handling.  They solve 2 different core problems.

I would actually solve the likely problem differently and use Azure Websites + WebJobs.  Its the same sort of thing.  You can bind the WebJob to an Azure Queue, table or blob and put messages on that storage mechanism, which the job picks up and does something with.  The web role I do not believe should rely on content coming back from the job.  The job may hit a SignalR Hub that you have on the AzureWeb site post completion, which pushes state back down to the affected parties.

Reference Materials:
WebJobs: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/

SignalR:  http://signalr.net/

Azure Web Apps: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/web/

Comment: Thanks David.  The question here is for Inter-role communication, I don't think WebAPI would be the best choice here?  The question is within a very specific architecture, e.g when every call is a simple request/response.  Does the bi-directional nature of ServiceBus add overhead, over a Simple (tcp/ip bound) WCF call with a response?